# Problem with JSP tags - Java code as value

Tags: java, jsp, attributes

I have problem with JSP tags - how I can insert into attribute value in Java code?
This is my code:

```
<%!
    String ii = new String();
 %>

   <%

    try {
        String id = request.getParameter("a");
        int i = Integer.valueOf(id);
        ii = String.valueOf(i);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        response.sendError(500);
    }

    %>
            <div style="float:right;margin-right:20px;">
                <strong>From: </strong> <em><post:ShowPm postId="<%=ii%>" /></em><br>
            </div>
```

If I run it, occurs error 500 - [stack](http://pastebin.com/m7d314e31)
On line 48 is this code:

```
<strong>From: </strong> <em><post:ShowPm postId="<%=ii%>" /></em><br>
```

I am using Struts 1 and JSP with own tags ( is my tag).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like you need to change your tld so that attribute can accept expressions:

```
   <attribute>
      ...
      <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
      ...
   </attribute>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just going to give some feedback on this JSP in general.

You realise that the variable "ii" won't be threadsafe?
ii is a class variable. 
Only one instance of a servlet is created, and multiple threads run through it.
Therefore you have the potential for multiple threads editing this value and printing out inconsistent results.

Solution: declare it as a local variable to the service method in <% scriptlet %> tags rather than <%! declaration %>

Just wondering what is the point of this code?  Turn a parameter into a number and then back again?  Is this some attempt at validation?   To me it seems like a whole lot of confusing unnecessary work.  Particularly just turning it back into a String.
If it is  required to be an integer, why doesn't your tag take an integer?
Or do the validation for itself?